# unix: how to tell if a string matches a regex

Tags: regex, linux, unix, pattern-matching, fish

Trying out [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/), so I'm translating my bash functions. The problem is that in one case, I'm using bash regexes to check if a string matches a regex. I can't figure out how to translate this into fish.

[Here](https://github.com/JoshCheek/dotfiles/blob/d1662522/dotfiles/profile#L49) is my example.

```
if [[ "$arg" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
...
```

- I looked into **sed**, but I don't see a way to get it to set its exit status based on whether the regex matches.
- I looked into delegating to **Ruby**, but again, getting the exit status set based on the match requires making this really ugly (see below).
- I looked into delegating back to **bash**, but despite trying maybe three or four ways, never got that to match.

**So, is there a way in *nix to check if a string matches a regex, so I can drop it into a conditional?**

---

Here is what I have that currently works, but which I am unhappy with:

```
# kill jobs by job number, or range of job numbers
# example: k 1 2 5
# example: k 1..5
# example: k 1..5 7 10..15
# example: k 1-5 7 10-15
function k
  for arg in $argv
    if ruby -e "exit ('$arg' =~ /^[0-9]+\$/ ? 0 : 1)"
      kill -9 %$arg
    else
      set _start (echo "$arg" | sed 's/[^0-9].*$//')
      set _end   (echo "$arg" | sed 's/^[0-9]*[^0-9]*//')

      for n in (seq $_start $_end)
        kill -9 %"$n"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard way is to use `grep`:

```
if echo "$arg" | grep -q -E '^[0-9]+$'
  kill -9 %$arg
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even realize there was the -E flag (always used awk for that), the `-q` flag, or that it would set its exit status based on whether it saw a match.

Comment: Install GNU grep to use -P (Perl regexp syntax) on OS X.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to use the built-in [string match](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string-match) subcommand

```
if string match -r -q  '^[0-9]+$' $arg
  echo "number!"
else
  echo "not a number"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting from version 3.2, Bash natively supports regexs, see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF

Comment: OP knew that, they're migrating away from Bash.